# How to connect a model/router and a router on the same network?

Tags: networking, router, lan, dhcp

I have a Vodafone modem router and this feeds my Linksys WRT3200 router via an ethernet cable straight to Linksys' "internet" port.

Now, both DCHP are enabled (Vodafone and Linksys) and I know this is a bit of an issue, because the internal IP addresses are 10.x.x.x whereas Vodafone's are 192.x.x.x. What I've done so far is to put a static IP for the Linksys inside of Vodafone's, that is 192.168.1.2. However all my devices at home are getting 10.x.x.x. How do I fix this?

By the way, when I disabled Vodafone's auto DHCP, I couldn't log back into it, so I know I screwed something up.

Comment: I ended up assigning 192.168.1.x to the Vodafone modem/router and 192.168.2.x to the Linksys.

Answer (score 2):

That's not an issue, because you have two separate networks.

A router connects IP networks (and separates them). The reason your Linksys has a dedicated "Internet" port is because it logically belongs to a different network from the "LAN" ports; the device *routes* IP packets between the two.

DHCP is made to be local to the network; it will not cross a router. When devices connected to the Linksys "LAN" send their DHCP requests, those are never sent through the "Internet" port and are never seen by the Vodafone LAN, nor by the Vodafone modem itself.

And vice versa, when a device on the Vodafone LAN sends out a DHCP request, the Linksys simply ignores it because its DHCP server is configured to only react on requests from the "LAN" network.

This is a normal, working configuration, although other things such as the double NAT (double port-forwarding) make it less than ideal. If both your routers support Wi-Fi, make sure to *not* give the same name to two separate networks at once.

---

If you actually wanted to create a *single* network, you should have used only the "LAN" ports on the Linksys and avoided the "Internet" port completely. (In this case, you can and should use identical Wi-Fi network names.)

However, if you do this, you *really* need to disable the LAN DHCP server on the Linksys.

When both routers respond with DHCP offers, the first one always wins and there's no configuration option to change that (other than adding a deliberate delay or turning off the second router's DHCP service entirely).

Comment: Ok maybe I need to clarify the "single network"... What I really want is to change my home network to be 192.168.1.x as all my devices are configured based on that range. I don't really care what Vodafone's modem IP address range will be. Very comprehensive answer though, thanks.